# Ajax и js функции

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript

Доброго времени суток. При написании сайта у меня возникла проблема с вызовами функций. Сайт на Ajax получает страницы, на полученных страницах не срабатывает вызов функций, хотя на главной всё Ок. Работает только если привязать к onsubmit, onload тоже не работает обычные средства вызова тоже. Страницы которые получаю через Ajax не запускают js функции которые прописаны в коде. В чем может быть проблема и как с этим бороться?

страница запрашивается через ajax:

```
function ajax() {
           $.ajax({
                type: method,
                url: "?",
                data: "page=test.php",
                success: function(html)
                {
                    document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = html;
                }
        });
}
```

содержание html кода в index которая запрашивает страницу и вставляет ситуацию не меняет, так что можно представить то что там просто:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=353, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
    <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<a href="#" onclick="ajax()">Вывести страницу</a>

<body class="mobile">

</body>
```

если я пропишу в test.php вызов скрипта через onload или просто `<script>test()</script>` то он не сработает. срабатывает только если я вставлю туда

```
<a href="#" onclick="test()">Запустить скрипт</a>
```

автоматический запуск сделать не получается. может ajax при получении страницы игнорирует автоматические js запросы? Пробовал саму функцию test() вставить в test.php, безрезультатно

Comment: Нужна более подробная постановка вопроса, с примерами кода

Comment: @windirprog, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Но как минимум новый вставленный код HTML не наследует автоматически события и их надо заново вешать.

Comment: @windirprog, пожалуйста, не удаляйте текст вопроса после того, как справились с проблемой. Кроме того, если нашли решение своей проблемы, пожалуйста, поделитесь им с сообществом.

Answer (score 2):

Событие onload срабатывает только тогда, когда текущая страница загружена, на простую вставку полученной через Ajax разметки это не распространяется. В конце концов Вы просто получили текст и вставили его в DOM.

Обработка тегов <script>...</script> происходит при формировании DOM дерева, после формирования простая вставка этого тега в разметку уже не сработает.

К тому же Ajax не привязывает все текущие события к вновь вставленной разметке, поэтому это желательно сделать самому.

Поэтому лучше просто повесить нужное после загрузки Ajax в самом обработчике success.

```
function ajax() {
        $.ajax({
                type: method,
                url: "?",
                data: "page=test.php",
                success: function(html)
                {
                    var tag = $("body");
                    tag.text(html);
                    $("a",tag).bind("click",ajax); 
                }
        });
}
```